# WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 Issue

Tags: windows-10, drivers, pci-express, visual-studio-2015

We are using Virtex-6 and try to use an FPGA board to send MSI by means of pciE. For this purpose, we install the necessary Jungo Drivers and libs even though we are facing a problem when we are trying to compile the code that is

"Error  MSB8020 The build tools for WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0') cannot be found. To build using the WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools, please install WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".   kp_gbv2 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets   57"

When I observe the problem I faced that WDK and SDK for Windows 10 should be downloaded and after I download the problem could not be solved. Do you have any idea about the solution? I can not find anything other than WDK and SDK issues. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Best Regards,
Cengizhan YAPICIOĞLU